# Performance, MySQL single query + PHP or multi-queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I usually try to have less MySQL queries possible in my projects, and then I format the datas using PHP.

I was wondering if the performances would be better with more MySQL queries which give me the exact data in the right format or if is better get all I need in a single query and then parse the result with PHP to get the Arrays I need.

Comment: And then tell us ;) Everything depends on what you want to do with this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the modern PHP, where encapsulation is one of the main points while writing code, a bunch of queries won't be executed, if you explicitly don't call the methods, which do the job.

Against some old-procedural style, where you can have in one page 100 queries and testing with is..() functions, which query to use, you will have a high load to your engine, because of the runtime compilation.

Thus, you can afford youself as much conditions as you want in a lot of queries, and less PHP to test it.

Let's have an example with something small.

Assume, you have something like a model, for an item called "Article". You want a search either by id, author or name. There's nothing wrong to have this:

```
public function getArticleById($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, author FROM article WHERE id = $id";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $this->db->fetch($query);

    return $result; //assuming you have query and fetch method, where the last one return an array/object
}

public function getArticleByName($name) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, author FROM article WHERE name = $name";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $this->db->fetch($query);

    return $result;
}

public function getArticleByAuthor($author) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, author FROM article WHERE author = $author";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $this->db->fetch($query);

    return $result;
}
```

Depends on what you want, you can use one of these methods. I usually asume, you can reuse the information returned by these methods in more than one page, because it returns the whole needed information for a single Article for example. On the other hand, I would assume you have used some bad practices, if, for example, the `article` has a `DateTime` field, and you use it in 3 pages with different formats - then you will need PHP to reformat the datetime, each time you use the method, which returns the info, and will be total overkill if you have 3 queries, which returns the datetime with different formats.

Also, total overkill is to request the whole table, and filter the information with PHP, instead of `WHERE`:

```
public function getArticle() {
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, author FROM article";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $this->db->fetch($query);

        return $result; 
    }

//...

foreach ($model->getArticle() as $article) {
    if ($article['name'] == $name) {
        //...
    }
```

Talking about performance is subjective thing, it really matters how and how often you query the database, so a single query which formats the data in given manner is reused often enough, you won't load your core.

Answer (score 2):

**As a rule of thumb..**

Usually, the rule I go by is to try to minimize the amount of requests you're making to some sort of persistent structure, like a Database. Database requests are very fast, but letting a language manipulate structures in memory is usually faster. It also depends on just how busy your DBMS is. Are there other people requesting from this table? Is it just you? Will it *always* be just you using it?

**If you want..**

You could do some benchmark tests, and simply time how long it takes for two threads to finish. One with the multiple MySQL queries; one with the single MySQL query. If you see a noticeable and consistent difference, then you've got your answer!

Comment: It's a kind of _Google Analytics_ service, it should be used by lot of people.

Comment: So you want to minimize the amount of time you're using the database. For one, you will see latency if lots of people are using it,and for another, the more people who make unnecessary requests, the slower it gets for everyone.

Comment: but, if I'm not wrong, MySQL has a cache for requests, so maybe it could helps?

Comment: It could, but it's still the DBMS handling it. Why not just make the single request; free up the resources for the other users and manipulate it in-memory, which I imagine will be quite a bit faster.